# Sensing high differential voltages using operational amplifiers

Tags: voltage, amplifier, differential, sensing

Is there any solution to sense high differential voltages using operational amplifiers (without using resistive voltage divider) ?

The input voltage range is [-30, 80] Volts.

I've searched on all operational amplifiers and no one fill this range.

I can't use a normal attenuator (Differential amplifier with gain < 1 ) since the common mode input voltage of the op amp is limited, and the input votlage has an independant ground ( I will not be sure if the CMIV will not be exceeded )

Thank you.

Comment: Why is a prescaling not an option? What precision do you need on this? And what do you mean with sense, as in, where is the output of your circuit going?

Comment: Are you saying that the independent ground could be hundreds or thousands of volts different to the ground for a circuit that might be useful in sensing?

Comment: Show us some schematic of source of voltage signal - there is always a possibility to measure any voltage, even when DM is in millivolts range and CM in kilovolts (I've designed such circuits which are now in production).

Comment: Use a gold-leaf-foil sensor, with laser interferometer readout of the tilt-angle of the two leaf's separation angle. The Interferometer needs OpAmps to process and recover the laser optical beat notes.

Comment: The precision i need in the global sensing is 0,5%.
For the independant ground, i don't have any information about it so i can not assume that the common mode voltage at V+ and V- will not be exceeded using a differential amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

You know the inputs are in the (+80V, -30V) range.  So, you could apply
a battery-powered voltmeter and read the difference directly.

Yes, of course it can be also be done with low-voltage op amps.   The high voltage can be turned into
a modest current, and with a few (-30, -35, -40V) power rails to power
an op amp, one can generate a ground-referenced (negative) voltage from each
input.   Do it twice, and you can apply a normal difference
amplifier on the translated/scaled voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkkSCG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The scheme (1) reduces the voltages
to something less, (2) applies an offset to near-ground levels.
$$A_{scaled} = -(A + 30) *( R8*R4)/(R1*R7) $$

so (80V, -30V) inputs are changed to (-0.550V, 0V) outputs

(There's some linearity errors near the (-30V) value, if that
end of the range is important, moving the power supplies down
by ten volts will clean it up).

Actually, though, voltage dividers aren't so bad; the proliferation
of power supplies is rather a nuisance, doing it this way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I'm trying to understand this schematic. I will get back to you once i will have a fixed idea about it.